# What are the historical reasons for processes receiving SIGTTYIN/TTOU instead of blocking?

Tags: terminal, history, signals

In unix, a process started from a terminal can (usually) not read or write to their terminal if it is backgrounded. In other cases when a process can't read/write to its terminal (or other file descriptor) it simply blocks, and continues running once the read or write can be completed. In the case of a process that is backgrounded, instead it receives SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU, which by default suspends the process. If the process is later foregrounded, the shell continues it.

Why was this behaviour designed like this? Blocking file descriptors are much easier to deal with than signals, as they often require no special handling at all. In other cases involving ttys (such as if the connection to the terminal can't handle the data rate) the processes just blocks. If a process needed to know about this it could check if it was foregrounded. Were there at the time any advantages to this design?

Of course this behaviour is now part of posix, so now it is fixed for 'historical reasons', but what were these historical reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The processes the shell spawns, usually have their stdin/stdout/stderr directly connected to the terminal. This allows the processes to do magic stuff like changing terminal settings, font, keyboard input modes etc.

So if the processes are not suspended, they would still try to read the keyboard inputs.

Processes that knows about this logic can then listen for the signals, and disable I/O if backgrounded

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Why not make the I/O block instead?

Comment: When multiple programs try to read (in blocking mode) from the same character resource, it will be random (to some extent) which process receives the data. And take this example. Two processes both try to read from the same resources. Process A receives one of the characters, and starts to process it, while processing, process B receives the second one since process A is for some short time not reading due to its processing.